# How reliable are amazon s3 access log files?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

We're moving to s3 to start serving some of the statically generated content for our web app.  We have been looking at a mechanism for building a metric system about the usage of our site and we were planning on parsing the access logs for S3 by passing additional information to be logged on the content GET requests.  We happened across the following [entry in the developers guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?LogDelivery.html):

> Best Effort Server Log Delivery
>
> The server access logging feature is
>   designed for best effort. You can
>   expect that most requests against a
>   bucket that is properly configured for
>   logging will result in a delivered log
>   record, and that most log records will
>   be delivered within a few hours of the
>   time that they were recorded.
>
> However, the server logging feature is
>   offered on a best-effort basis. The
>   completeness and timeliness of server
>   logging is not guaranteed. The log
>   record for a particular request might
>   be delivered long after the request
>   was actually processed, or it might
>   not be delivered at all. The purpose
>   of server logs is to give the bucket
>   owner an idea of the nature of traffic
>   against his or her bucket. It is not
>   meant to be a complete accounting of
>   all requests.

We are wondering what other people have experienced with respect to the delivery of access logs?  Our alternative is to build an HTTP server and try to meter the metrics ourselves with a different call, but we think that parsing the log files could prove to be less work.  We'd like to know if people have seen situations where delivery didn't take place to try to gauge about how accurate we could hope to be because some of the metrics we gather are used in some of our business processes.

Comment: Fair question, I think "best effort" stems from their "any server can crash" approach.  They likely copy logs off when a server's gracefully suspended/shut down, but they don't keep logs on premium (backed up, guaranteed) storage space - so they can't guarantee that log-copy in all cases.  If you want more reliable logging you could always set up your own mechanism to move the logs to a [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/), [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/).

Comment: Also take a look at https://www.s3stat.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was surprised how large my log files on S3 had gotten in under a month.  It wasn't necessary for my app to parse the logs on Amazon but I like your approach.  From what I've seen, you can expect the log files to be accurate and complete.  Based on their CYA warning, the logs should not be used for anything critical.

Answer (score 3):

We have been using S3 to log relatively large amounts of data (in the order of 100M rows). We needed to rely on S3 access logs for a specific purpose and we are observing few issues that might be important for potential users of access logs to be aware of:

- We see (few) log entries showing up many days after they are supposed to be created
- We see duplicate entries logging a single S3 transaction (currently investigating)
- There also seems to be cases where a log entry is actually not created (currently investigating)

My recommendation is to avoid relying on S3 access logs if data accuracy and completeness is critical.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an answer to your question, but ...

Unless your static files require some sort of authorization (signed URLs for downloads, etc.), I see no good use-case to use S3 to serve static content.

It's not a CDN and not meant to be used as one. ;-)

At the very least, I'd recommend to use cloudfront but IMHO it's too expensive (and doesn't perform very well in comparison to others). I'd recommend someone like [edgecast](http://www.edgecast.com/) or [cachefly](http://www.cachefly.com/) since they offer more for your money.\

They also provide you with (more or less) extensive staticstics and a lot of nice features like easy purging and invalidation of your cache.

Comment: A good use case would be serving large files such as long MP3's or videos that would tie up your local server with it's finite resources, so that your server can focus on scaling the application logic.